# Bootstrap centering the navigationbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm currently learning to use Bootstrap3 and i'm having some trouble centering my navigationbar. I've read several topics with the same problem, but none of their solutions has worked for me. I might be missing something completley obvious, so help would be appreciated! All the elements are currently being shoved to the left of the bar, and I want them centered.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the best way but it works.

make bootstrap's ul element's width 100% to start off with.

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="text-align:center;width:100%;margin:auto">`

then just give the first li element a margin percentage, this could change depending on how many elements you have on the bar, so just experiment around with them.

```
 <li class="active" style="margin-left: 35%;"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
```